# Crash on Apple Review - iOS

Tags: crash, ios9, xcode8, ios10

I had submit application several time to review.
But every time Apple tester said the application crash.
I test on my application in environment IPV4. 
Totally no crash, but Apple tester said crash when launch as below.
It's the problem about IPV6? I can't test in environment IPV6.

> Thank you for your resubmission. We were unable to review your app as
>   it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help
>   troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1) Start the app on a device 2) the app attempts to launch and crashes
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an
>   IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch
>   without crashing.

```
Date/Time:           2016-10-25 13:02:41.6759 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-10-25 13:02:40.6012 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010014c3fc
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   BBBApps                         0x000000010014c3fc 0x1000e4000 + 427004
1   BBBApps                         0x0000000100149420 0x1000e4000 + 414752
2   UIKit                           0x000000018d0a342c 0x18d021000 + 533548
3   UIKit                           0x000000018d2b3b70 0x18d021000 + 2698096
4   UIKit                           0x000000018d2b98e0 0x18d021000 + 2722016
5   UIKit                           0x000000018d2ce080 0x18d021000 + 2805888
6   UIKit                           0x000000018d2b68c4 0x18d021000 + 2709700
7   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000188d898bc 0x188d4f000 + 239804
8   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000188d89728 0x188d4f000 + 239400
9   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000188d89ad0 0x188d4f000 + 240336
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187196278 0x1870b9000 + 905848
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187195bc0 0x1870b9000 + 904128
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001871937c0 0x1870b9000 + 894912
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001870c2048 0x1870b9000 + 36936
14  UIKit                           0x000000018d09c5dc 0x18d021000 + 505308
15  UIKit                           0x000000018d097360 0x18d021000 + 484192
16  BBBApps                         0x00000001000ea5e4 0x1000e4000 + 26084
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001860a45b8 0x1860a0000 + 17848
```

Here the crash report from Crashlytics:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  BBBApps                       0x10009183c specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift:39)
1  BBBApps                       0x10008ecbc @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x19235b42c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
3  UIKit                          0x19256bb70 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3524
4  UIKit                          0x1925718e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
5  UIKit                          0x192586080 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3134 + 48
6  UIKit                          0x19256e8c4 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
7  FrontBoardServices             0x18e0418bc __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
8  FrontBoardServices             0x18e041728 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
9  FrontBoardServices             0x18e041ad0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18c44e278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18c44dbc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18c44b7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18c37a048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
14 UIKit                          0x1923545dc -[UIApplication _run] + 608
15 UIKit                          0x19234f360 UIApplicationMain + 208
16 BBBApps                       0x10008f9d4 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18b35c5b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your mac to share an IPV6 network.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Option-click on the Sharing preference pane
3. Option-click on Internet Sharing
4. A Create IPv6 Only Network checkbox will appear
5. Check Create IPv6 Only Network (this may also be labeled Create NAT64 Network)
6. Select the interface to share out over (usually this will be WiFi, to allow iOS devices to connect.)
7. Check the box to start internet sharing

[Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971)

Comment: I had check on this way, but no crash.

Comment: Are you testing with iOS10? (because i see you added a 'iOS9' tag in this question)

Comment: Yes, I test on iOS10

Answer (score 0):

Trace/BPT trap 5 is usually related to the missing shared libraries ([`.dylib` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)).

In your case the following line suggests you which one is missing:

```
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18b35c5b8 (Missing)
```

Make sure your app has proper access to it (compiled with it) or you have included it correctly along with your app.

You can use `otool` (`-L`) command-line tool to check more details about missing dependencies.